# Linear regression using running parameters

Tags: regression, least-squares, nonlinear-regression

I always asked myself what was the right method name for a simple linear regression using *running* parameters.

I mean that instead of using constant mean $\bar{y}$ or $\bar{x}$ for the estimation of $ \alpha$ we use a simple moving average of $x$ and $y$ as well as a running standard deviation and a running correlation coefficient.

I've heard of least square moving average as well as local regression/running line but I'm not sure what is the correct formulation of such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be thinking of a [Savitzky-Golay filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter). This works by sliding a window across the signal. A local polynomial model is fit in each window using least squares. Local linear or quadratic models are the most common choices (but you could also think of a simple moving average as a 0th order Savitzky-Golay filter). Evaluating the model at the center of each window gives a smoothed version of the signal. It's also possible to differentiate the model to obtain smoothed derivatives.

When the samples are uniformly spaced, computation is very efficent--both smoothing and differentiation can be performed by convolving the signal with particular 
[FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) coefficients, rather than by estimating each local model from scratch. But, to avoid edge effects in this case, it's necessary to iterate through points at the edges of the signal.

Related [local polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) techniques (e.g. LOESS, LOWESS) may also use weights to place greater emphasis on points near the center of the window.

Answer (score 0):

As to the 'right method name for a simple linear regression using running parameters', I would suggest bivariate time series analysis of say  univariate exponential moving averages (or autoregressive) time series models (see 'Example of Multivariate Time Series Analysis' [here](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc451.htm)). Also, autoregressive  models with a type of Markov switching in mean may be applicable. See historic review and comments in [this paper](https://economics.indiana.edu/documents/papers/a-new-approach-to-model-regime-switching1.pdf).

Personally, I would put more trust in models like this,'Switching-regime regression for modeling and predicting a stock market return' [described here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00181-019-01763-9).